# Is there a way to macro unit test in kdb+?

Tags: unit-testing, kdb

I have seen a few different unit testing approaches online using qunit and k4unit but I can only get them testing on single functions. I was hoping that I could run a unit test that check the daily checks I execute each day such as, "has the nightjobs ran correctly?", "are the dashboards on the WebUI up?", "did the deploy script run with no errors?". Is there built in kdb+ functionality for these kind of tests or a clean way to adapt the qunit or k4unit unit tests? Or will it require a script written from scratch?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a unit test is what you're looking for here. Some kind of reporting mechanism for jobs would be more appropriate. Within your existing jobs you could generate some kind of alert to indicate the job's success/failure. This [qmail](https://github.com/t-martin/qmail) library may be useful for that.

I'm not sure what kind of system you're using, but AquaQ Analytics' [TorQ](https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ) system has a [reporter](https://aquaqanalytics.github.io/TorQ/Processes/#reporter) process which can (amongst other things) email alerts for specific processes.

(Disclaimer: I'm an employee of AquaQ Analytics)